# C/C++: What's faster: a for loop, or incrementing a pointer

Tags: c++, c, performance, loops, pointers

I am wondering which of the following code segments would be fastest, assuming that the goal is to read from the elements of type `T` in amount `numElements` pointed to by `somePointer` and do something with them. I'm specifically interested in the efficiency of the looping structure itself, not what's being done with the elements.

1st Candidate

```
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    T val = somePointer[i];
    ... // Do something
}
```

2nd Candidate

```
T* tempPointer = somePointer;
T* endPointer = somePointer + numElements;
while (tempPointer < endPointer) {
    T val = *tempPointer;
    ... // Do something
    tempPointer++;
}
```

Certainly the first candidate is more clear and less prone to errors. However, if it is actually getting compiled into the code it seems it would generate, I would think it would be slower. Using a `for` loop requires an increment of `i` every loop iteration, as well as an offset from the address pointed to by `somePointer` by amount `i * sizeOf(t)` before dereferencing. The pointer incrementation method seems to require only one addition operation for every loop cycle, thus leading me to believe it would be faster.

However, as I understand compilers try to vectorize `for` loops as possible with SIMD instructions; if the compiler can successfully detect an opportunity for vectorization in a `for` loop but not with incrementing pointers, the `for` then would seem to be the faster option. Of course, for all I know, the compiler is detecting cases where `for` loops can be converted to pointer incrementation and making the conversion before the vectorization, which would make it irrelevant.

In short, in real-world scenarios, which is faster?

Comment: The question actually does not make sense, since the compiler would optimize at least entire functions (and often, the whole translation unit). Some compilers would even transform one of the version into the other.

Comment: If speed is important use ++i and ++tempPointer

Comment: @cha: you are wrong, at least for current C optimizing compilers ([GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/), both with `-O2` at least)

Comment: It depends, so why don't you measure it.

Comment: @Textfield: **leave such micro-optimizations to the *compiler*** ; focus more effort on writing *readable* and *maintainable* code.

Comment: C or C++ source code does not have any "speed" associated with it. The concept can only be applied to the translated executable code. And performance characteristics of that executable code will depend greatly on the capabilities of the compiler and compiler setup, especially when it comes to matters of obvious micro-optimizations. In most cases, obvious applications of "pointer as iterator" technique (your second example) will have the same performance as index access (your first example), simply because modern compilers are smart enough to generate the same code for both.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch. Perhaps I am too old-school. I came from the C background and always remebered this. Check [this](answers)

Comment: @cha: yes, you are too old-school. Current C compilers are able of a lot of optimizations, so your advice does not make any sense today. Likewise, using `register` is useless (except to forbid the address-of `&` operator)

Comment: 3rd candidate: `for (T val : someArray)`. C++ only, but by avoiding helper variables the compiler can easier prove there's no aliasing going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically, the answer to your question is the former, simpler code.

> An
>       actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
>       value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by
>        calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

This is a quote from the C standard demonstrating the power placed upon the compiler to make optimisations. In this case, the parts of the expression that aren't needed are related to the `int` index (which should probably be a `size_t`).

**Realistically, the answer to your question is also the former, simpler code.** You may be pleasantly surprised to find that the common compilers of today can perform optimisations such as the one you mention (and more complex, yet) *quite easily*. However, due to the many aspects of computer systems that combine to build a bigger picture of performance, it's not possible to give an answer as to which of these will be faster... We'd need to know every relevant aspect about your implementation (CPU, memory, OS, compiler, etc).

See ["Will it Optimise?"](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/will-it-optimize.html), for a few similar examples that gcc happily optimises. This is a form of [loop invariant computation](http://leto.net/docs/C-optimization.php) optimisation. Make sure you compile your code with full optimisations enabled (`-O3`, typically).

It's not just optimisation that you need to consider, however. As you've mentioned, the former, simpler code is easier to read. This is important for anybody who may end up maintaining your code.

When considering optimisation, here's a handy hint: Your boss will want to see something that works, even if it's too slow, sooner rather than later. If you don't have a boss, great! Consider that you can't measure *optimised* code without having something to compare it to, however...

**Write clear, concise code for the purpose of maintainability.** If your boss (or your team, or yourself, or whatever) decides when it's complete that it's not fast enough, use your profiler to determine where the most significant bottlenecks are, then you should have some idea of what to focus on... You'll be optimising your time *and* your code.

Once you've completed an optimisation, use your profiler again to determine whether or not it was an effective optimisation. This way you remove the negative effect that your guesswork *could* have.

Todays common compilers can often even perform optimisations based on the output of a profiler. This technique is called "profile-guided optimisation", and might be worth researching...

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, the worst case running time of a for loop, and also a while loop like this one is O(n). That said, it will grow linearly based on the number of elements you have.

In this case, it is of very little value of considering which one is faster, as they are essentially the same, assuming that what you'll be doing under

```
//Do something
```

is the same.

When considering the efficiency of your program, it is worth considering both running time and memory efficiency.

I think what's written within your for loop/while loop is of greater importance of what's affecting your running time.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using GCC or MinGW or Cygwin on intel boards.
For loop has built in support in intel boards for counter incrementing now if you consider the second loop in that case the pointer should increment with the size of the data type it is pointing to which will ask the compiler to put more code in to the assembly code and eventually will increase overheads of CPU increasing more CPU cycles to complete your code but in first case the compiler will generate assembly code in order to keep counter variable i in the register itself making it easy for CPU to compare and continue/break the loop.If you write both code in two files(one.c and two.c say) and run the following command

```
gcc -S one.c
gcc -S two.c
```

to see the assembly code and If you understand x86 assembly probably you can understand more clearly what I want to say.My understanding says that first loop will work faster if you go deep down to how CPU and assembly works.

Comment: Both `somePointer[i]` and `somePointer++` need to jump X bytes.